# Use Q package on Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, q

I want to use  [Q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) on an Angular 2, Ionic 2 and TypeScript application. I have something like this, but it throws a `Cannot read property 'defer' of undefined` exception.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Q } from 'q';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class MyClass {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, platform: Platform, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {    
  }

  doSomething() {
    let deferred = Q.defer();
    deferred.resolve(true);
  }
}
```

I installed Q with

```
npm install q
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using Q? `rxjs`, which Angular 2 requires, integrates with the standard ES6 Promise.

Comment: No, there isn't. But, if i want to use a third party npm package, i will have the same issue?

Comment: It depends which package, how you add it to your project, what kind of bundling you're using, how you use it, ...

Comment: But with Q, it's possible? It would a nice starting point